# Pass trigger/event from Plugin to main application on close

Tags: c#, plugins, triggers

So I have a program that runs a simple "Plugin Selection". For ease of use, when the Plugin loads up, I make the original application form invisible.

The problem is that when the Plugin closes, I can't think of a way to pass a trigger back to the original application to check if the Plugin closes, and then make the Main application visible again (or for simplicity's sake, just close).

My first attempt didn't go so well:

```cs
// Looks for the instance of the plugin, and loads the instance, and opens the Form in that instance
if (LoadPlugin(plugin))
{
    // While the instanced plugin Form is visible 
    while (Global.Plugins.AvailablePlugins.Find(plugin).Instance.PluginForm.Visible)
    {
        // Makes this form invisible, to maintain the parent Application instance to host the Plugin
        this.Visible = false;
    }
    // When the plugin form closes, close this form, and end the program.
    this.Close();
}
```